# What part of speech is veteran in 'He had obtained and provisioned a veteran ship...'?

Tags: adjectives

> He had obtained and provisioned **a veteran ship** called the Discovery and had recruited a crew of twenty-one, the largest he had ever commanded.

What part of speech is veteran in above sentence?

Is it adjective because its describing a ship or is it noun taking veteran ship together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well *veteran ship* is not a compound noun  so *veteran* in this case is an adjective. It can also be a noun,  but there's no need to say it's a noun here.

See [this dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/veteran) for some uses of *veteran* as an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

> veteran

is used as an adjective, it could be replaced with

> previously used
>   older